# send http form GET in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking for a way to be able to send a GET HTTP request form Json style in dart. Everywhere I find that people had problems with the POST but no document about the GET. the issue is that if I write http.get(Uri.parse(uri)) I can't put the body: (where the form would go). it only lets me write body when it is a POST.
i want to be able to run the next code with GET. The Uri.parse (i dont know why, but its the only way that allow me to get de URL)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  postTest() async {
    final uri = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/qna/';

    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri), body: {
      'pregunta': 'contacto',
    });

    print(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter WebView '),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: TextButton(onPressed: postTest, child: Text('Push me')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `get` method support only two arguments: `url` and `headers`. You can find full method description in [Official documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html).

Comment: You can't put the body in a GET because [GET is used only to retrieve remote data, and not to insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477374/9997212).

Comment: ha sorry guy for be a newbie ... im learning :) . but i have an answer ... if i want to do a login , its mean that i need to do it as a POST request ? because i cant not send a form in GET request... but every mobile app do with POST ? im confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant add body in get request. but you can pass the data in the query param.
like this

```
postTest() async {
    final uri = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/qna?pregunta=contacto';

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(uri));

    print(response.body);
  }
```

Comment: ha sorry guy for be a newbie ... im learning :) . but i have an answer ... if i want to do a login , its mean that i need to do it as a POST request ? because i cant not send a form in GET request... but every mobile app do with POST ? im confuse

Comment: you have to use post for login.